# How to segment time series data into 3 column and 3 channels?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, convolution

I have a time series data(1000 data points) with following column names :

X  ,  Y  ,  Z   ,  A   ,  B  .

I want to generate 10 segments each of 100 data points with 3 channels, where the first channel contains the column   X,A,B   , the second channel Y,A,B and the third channel  Z,A,B?

How can I accomplish this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Numpy

To rearrange the time series into the 10 segments, you can simply use `np.reshape`.

Example data of shape `(XYZAB, timepoints)`:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,10,(5,1000))
print a.shape
>> (5L, 1000L)
```

Reshaping into the ten segments, resulting in `(XYZAB, segments, timepoints)`:

```
b = np.reshape(a,(5,10,100))
print b.shape
>> (5L, 10L, 100L)
```

At this point, it may not be desirable to create what you call 'channels', as you would triplicate parts of your data (A and B) without really making it easier to access that data. You could access e.g. `XAB` simply like this:

```
xab = b[(0,3,4),:,:]
```

If you absolutely need the channels as individual copies, you can simply get them like this:

```
c = np.array([b[(0,3,4),:,:],
              b[(1,3,4),:,:],
              b[(2,3,4),:,:]])
print c.shape
>> (3L, 3L, 10L, 100L)
```

Which results in an array of shape `(channel,column,segment,timepoints)`, where `column` refers to the original column names (e.g. `(X,A,B)` for channel `0`).

#### Pandas

Just saw the `pandas` tag on your question, so...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a.T, columns=list('XYZAB'))
```

Split into segments of 100 time points as a list of dfs:

```
segments = []
for group, segment in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 100):
    segments.append(segment)
```

Or, even better, just create a new column that indicates which segment each row belongs to:

```
df['segment'] = df.apply(lambda x : x.name // 100, axis=1)
```

At this point it's probably again best not to triplicate your data and instead use the df as it is. You can easily apply operations per time segment using `df.groupby(['segment'])`, while selecting columns of interest by standard column selection, e.g.

```
df.groupby(['segment'])['X','A','B'].mean()
```

to get the per-segment mean of columns X, A and B.

Of course you can create e.g. a list or dict of 'channels' in this way, if you really need it.

```
channels = {'XAB':df[['segment','X','A','B']],
            'YAB':df[['segment','Y','A','B']],
            'ZAB':df[['segment','Z','A','B']]}
```

And you can make this into a pandas `Panel`:

```
pnl = pd.Panel(channels)
```

The best data structure to use depends on your particular use-case, but in general I would avoid using Panels and stick with either the 2D `df` or the 3D array (i.e. `b`).